# lxml library in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, lxml

I've included this library as a layer to my lambda function but when I go to test it I get the error: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml'

There are multiple posts about people having this issue and some say to that I need to build it to compile some c libraries. Most posts say to look for another file or folder name 'lxml' which I've verified is not the issue.

I'm able to run the same code I've deployed to my layer on my local linux workstation and it runs without an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my lambda was running python version 3.8 and that version is not compatible with the version of lxml I am using 4.5.1. Changing the run time to 3.7 fixed the issue. Hope this helps someone.